# PHP - How to modify the value of the object in the array (array of objects)?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, arrayobject

I have problem in modifying the value of the array of objects.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[25]
      public 'time1' => string '09:00:00' (length=8)
      public 'btm_01' => string '40.00' (length=5)
      public 'bto_01' => string '41.00' (length=5)
      public 'rs_01' => string '42.00' (length=5)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[26]
      public 'time1' => string '10:00:00' (length=8)
      public 'btm_01' => string '41.00' (length=5)
      public 'bto_01' => string '40.00' (length=5)
      public 'rs_01' => string '40.00' (length=5)
```

I need a for loop to remove '.00' in each value the array of objects. To remove '.00' it's easy matter but after I can remove it, I still can't replace the old value with the new one in array of objects.

Could you help me, how to modify the value in array of objects with PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nah,

It so simple.. I'll give you an example

```
 foreach($data['bottom_max'] as $key => $value)
 {
     foreach ($value as $name_row => $val_row) {
         if (strpos($val_row, '.0')) {
             $tmp = substr($val_row, 0, -3);
             $data['bottom_max'][$key]->$name_row = $tmp;
         }
     }
 }
```

Hope it's answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

try this (access the obejct by reference):

```
foreach($array as & $obj) {
    $obj->time1 = $newvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy :

```
<?php
$object[0]->time1 = '10:00:00';
?>
```

It just like what you imagine